# How to encrypt neo4j data?

Tags: encryption, neo4j, cypher

I am working on neo4j graph database recently and i want to encrypt my data.I know that Neo4j does not have any built-in encryption.i have some nodes and relations between that nodes.so how can i encrypt my data?

Answer (score 1):

The [security checklist](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/security/checklist/) has some suggestions for how to keep your data secure, and mentions encryption.

Also, the operating system on which you are running the neo4j server may support the encryption of your Db's data folder.